# Mongoose currency does not show decimals

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a Schema with a 'price' field using Mongoose currency and follow the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-currency) on it. However the output does not show two decimals (499 instead of 4.99). If I use console.log to print the price, it shows the desired results, with two decimals. I wonder whether I misunderstood the Mongoose documentation on Currency or does the cause lie somewhere else.

This is my schema.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var assert = require('assert');
var Dishes = require('./models/stackmodel');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';mongoose.connect(url);
var db = mongoose.connection;

var product = new Dishes({ price: '4.99' });

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
  // we're connected!
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
  
  // create a new dish
  Dishes.create({
    name: 'Uthapizza',
 price: (product.price/100).toFixed(2),  
  }, function (err, dish) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Dish created!');
    console.log(dish);
 
 console.log(typeof (product.price/100).toFixed(2));

 console.log((product.price/100).toFixed(2));
           
 db.collection('dishes').drop(function () {
            db.close();
      });
   });
});
```

This is my model.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require('mongoose-currency').loadType(mongoose);
var Currency = mongoose.Types.Currency;

// create a schema
var dishSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },

  price: {
    type: Currency,
 require: true,
 min: -20000,
 max: 50000,
    default: ''
  }
});

var Dishes = mongoose.model('Dish', dishSchema);

// make this available to our Node applications
module.exports = Dishes;
```

And this is the print-out.

```html
C:\ass2>node stack
Connected correctly to server
Dish created!
{ __v: 0,
  name: 'Uthapizza',
  _id: 58cd3dbd4319c51264489d8d,
  price: 499 }
string
4.99

C:\ass2>
```

I have searched on the web, including on this site, but found no solution so far.

I use:

- OS is Windows 7 32-bit
- mongoose@4.8.6
- node version v6.10.0
  and while running npm list I got the following message (I suspect this might be the reason why I got the above problem):

```html
npm ERR! extraneous: currency@3.0.0 C:\node_modules\currency
npm ERR! extraneous: mocha@3.2.0 C:\node_modules\mocha
npm ERR! extraneous: mongoose-currency@0.2.0 C:\node_modules\mongoose-currency
```

Thank's a lot beforehand.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting. Reading the documentation, basically all it does is try to extract a price from a string, multiply the price by 100, and store it in the database. That's it.

Comment: Read the documents: 
It basically says the number is multiplied by 100 before storing it in database. You will have to change your business logic to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly late to the party but for future folks, this is how mongoose-currency stores float values. It first multiplies by 100 and then stores it. You should divide by 100 when retrieving values.
According to their readme on GitHub:

> Saves a String as an integer (by stripping non-digits and multiplying by 100) to prevent rounding errors when performing calculations (See gotchas for details)

Example:

```
var product = new Product({ price: "$1,200.55" });
product.price; // Number: 120055
product.price = 1200;
product.price; // Number 1200 It will not round or multiply. Stored AS IS and should represent $12.00
```